# Python - Failed to remove all spaces

Tags: python

[image]

Hello, I tried to

**Desired result:**
1. Import data from EXCEL
2. Remove all spaces (include **spaces between and new line**s)
3. Group by column 'BOM', and run the distinct count of 'NAME'

**Problem**:

1. I have tried 2 ways (remove\ join split) found on previous posts on stackoverflow, but failed as seen in below image.
2. In the result part, please see the column 'BOM', why above there is no spaces, but with spaces in the 2nd result?

Many thanks for any advice.

```
enter code here

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
import os
import xlrd

os.chdir('C:/Users/mac/Desktop')
t=pd.read_excel('testdata.xlsx')

# 1st method to remove spaces
#while ' ' in t:
#    t.remove(' ')

#2nd method to remove spaces
def remove(t):
    return "".join(t.split())

print (t,'\n------')

t1=t.fillna(method='ffill')
t1.groupby(['BOM']).NAME.nunique()     
# Group by column "BOM", and then distinct count based on Name
```

Comment: A [MCVE] must be provided as text in the body of the question, not an embedded image (let alone a barely readable one like you've provided). Please edit the question to include the full [MCVE] properly. None of the code in the image even attempts to remove the spaces (`remove` is never called), so even the image fails to be reproducible.

Comment: Post relevant code directly with the question, it is of limited use in a screenshot.

Comment: What about  ```for col in ["BOM","NAME"]: t[col] = t[col].str.strip()```? PS: post code first...

Comment: @ Alexander B.,many thanks, it works~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do:

```
df.NAME = df.NAME.str.replace(' ', '')
df.BOM = df.BOM.str.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is actually the data has dozens of columns, the example posted here has been simplified. So if there is a way that I could apply to 100+columns without typing hundred of code lines above?

Comment: I tried your recommended solution, the result is still with spaces~~~

Comment: If you want to apply the space stripping to all columns except for a few, you could e.g. do a for loop on 'set(df.columns) - set(list-of-columns-to-exclude-from-stripping)', and apply the stripping as 'df[col] = df[col].str.replace(" ", "")'.
In general though, for loops should be avoided when working with pandas in favor of more efficient pandas methods, if possible.

Comment: while ' ' in t:   t.remove(' ') ,  I tried this loop,yet failed to get the result. Besides, I feel it is wiered why I simply run the "t.BOM=t.BOM.str.replace(' ' ,'')", no space is removed.....

Comment: Start by just printing t.BOM and then t.BOM.str.replace(' ', ''), do you not see a difference?

Comment: the spaces inbetween have been removed, but the new line "\n" has not been removed (C4 in EXCEL picture)

Comment: ，by using for col in ['BOM','NAME']: t[col] = t[col].str.strip()  ,it works, many thanks

Comment: As I said in comments -  use strip() instead of replace(). Strip takes care of (as far as I know) any type of spaces to the left and right of its content. Otherwise, you would have to do replace(...).replace(...)...

Comment: The usage of either str.strip or str.replace depends on whether one wants to remove spaces only from left and right (strip) or all spaces (replace). As the author of the question wanted to remove all spaces, I suggested str.replace.